# Infer method type from its parent object

Tags: typescript

I have an object type that can have any properties it wants, but one of its properties must be a function (if defined). The problem is: I want this function type to include all of the other properties as its argument. See [the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthjV8AnQuQgM0mABUBPGAUwGUrUZHU4cTOzjAAjABYAHACYAnAGIBQ9kWLF2AO0gBaAKwAGCUZl6JANgBQkNu1AA5QgElNddpQA8TAHygAvKAA2kwAusGg7AAekFoAJnCgAIaaLKAA-KAGoAigmuwAbu4hANyW1ragLrFRidgANnYBAN6WoG1BANbsLDlwkJSomsghOckslgC+ZTYcoACihdpwXhHRcQlVNfWNlZrVkbUNvs2t7YSaAGKEhGk5ABSJlMg5APLkkF4ANKBdLPTzi0gcG8AEp-L58oRULFJtMKldCCsojE9hs9lsjv5QExQAAyAFaIEeRwuNyeHzeMrVfB1R52OiYTT4SCoc6gGJ9JFrVG7faHdjeO50a45HH4hFeUE5SHQ6YiSB3FrtJI5MSfU5tc4Ih5PMFK5XtECgABEM3Y-0eyGNoDg4EImDqsVA2DsxqaKtymGILsooAmxo1fsmIKAA) to understand better.

```
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

type Indexable = {
    [key: string]: any
}

type Events<T extends Indexable = Indexable> = {
    onFoo?: (arg: Omit<T, keyof Events>) => void
}

type Foo<T extends Indexable> = T & Events<NoInfer<T>>

declare function test<T extends Indexable>(foo: T & Foo<T>): void

test({
    a: 1,
    onFoo(arg) {
        // "typeof arg" should be "{ a: number }"
    }
})
```

I imagine it's an issue with circular types, since [this basic example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthjV8AnQuQgM0mABUBPGAUwGUrUZHU4cTOzjAAjABYAHACYAnAGIBQ9kWLF2AO0gBaAKwAGCUZl6JANgBQkNu1AA5QgElNddpQA8TAHygAvKAA2kwAusGg7AAekFoAJnCgAIaaLKAA-KAGoAigmuwAbu4hANyW1ragLrFRidgANnYBAN6WoG1BANbsLDlwkJSomsghOckslgC+ZdX4dYmUdnSYmviQqISaoDF9XhHRcQlVNfXs3gAUdISEOUygAGSgLe2gGwBiV2fzyDmOLm6ePgAlDl8oRULFJsDQKDwWVtpAzk92okcmIADStdpvD5fQGPTHPNogUAAIhsHHoSUoyBJoDg4EImDqsVA2DsJKaSRymkwxDZlFAExJBMFkKAA) also doesn't work.

Comment: blecch, looks like type inference really doesn't want to work this way.  Have you considered having `test()` take two arguments, one of type `T` and the other of type `(arg: T) => void` ?

Comment: @jcalz I'd rather have broken types than take 2 arguments. 

Comment: Maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I can't get the type inference to work the way you want.  No matter what I do, either `T` fails to infer, or it infers but the `onFoo` property's argument isn't properly infer.    I'd probably consider this less of a compiler bug and more of a design limitation.  Possibly it's related to not having a genuine [non-inferential type parameter usage site](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for the `onFoo` parameter. And possibly it has something to do with how many [passes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31892#issuecomment-506074016) the type inference algorithm needs to make in order to succeed.  I'm really not sure.  I do know that when I fight with the compiler like this, I usually lose.  So, it might be worth trying to do something less controversial.

A more straightforward approach is to use two function parameters (which I see you don't want to do), as in:

```
const makeOnFoo = <T>(
  foo: T,
  onFoo?: (arg: T) => void
): T & { onFoo?: (arg: T) => void } => Object.assign(foo, { onFoo });
```

That function will infer exactly the way you want, I believe, where the inferred `arg` will be of type `T`.  And if you have `test()` defined like this:

```
declare function test<T>(
  foo: T & { onFoo?: (arg: Omit<T, "onFoo">) => void }
): void;
```

You can at least *use* `makeFoo()` to get the inference you want:

```
test(
  makeOnFoo({ a: 1 }, arg => {
    console.log(arg.a.toFixed()); // okay
  })
);
```

I don't know if that's acceptable for you, but at least it plays more nicely with the compiler.

---

Oh well, hope that helps somewhat. Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMDyYBiIQwLwwA8AKgHwAUAsAFAwwBmOAXDMQDQ13jYgD8L5BACcA5i2IBKfKRgA3EAEsAJjQniYAMhgBvGNxz8Yg0eKl4Z85TAC+0mGgBGAKxTAoAOgQQICkWHKMIGw6elg4NhIA3DQ0Sq4ANsIoDACuYG4K4DBQKNAkFJwMzKyaIfp8AsJi9nAKUCTBAETljaRmFopKNqoslkrR1DQ50FS08MjoYSDkuggsAIw2wVV22oV0oJAg8Sju8SAixiKe7lAgmAoAHihK5BJRhdYSqgNAA)